# Difference between 留神，留意，留心？

Tags: meaning, difference

I am now learning 近义词 and got a problem with distinguishing the difference between  留神，留意，留心. The textbook says:

> 他干什么特别留心，看书时也常常做笔记 （留神and留意arent allowed here）
>   多亏我对他留了一点心，这个情况没有告诉他 （留神 and 留意 arent allowed here）
>   你看得出来他吗？ 我没有留意 （留神 and 留心 arent allowed here）

Why are some correct and some wrong?

Comment: This is a great project you're embarked on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should understand the three characters in the words firstly.
心：Mind
意：Sense
神: Focus

So add 留(*keep*) before them, becomes:

- 留心：Keep in mind --> remember
- 留意：Keep in sensitive --> ?
- 留神：Keep on focus  --> look out / be careful

My translation may not accurate in English, if someone have better translation, please comment below.

In your example,

- sentence 1 talking about reading/studying, so 留心 should be the only correct word.
- Sentence 2, here 留心 is separated, it's a derivative usage in my opinion. It means "keep defensive (because I remember he did something bad.)".
- Sentence 3, I don't understand the meaning... and I don't want to guess (although I could) since it's a tutorial/exam, it should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

The level of care or attention or focus:
留心 > 留意 > 留神

so for example if you agreed to help somebody to look into something, you can say:
我会给你留心的 sounds most serious and dedicated

我会给你留意的 also OK, but no promises

我会给你留神的 only if I have the spare time and engery

But, like the examples you have mentioned, the usages are mostly dictated by conventions than anything intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Chinese word is influence by culture of Buddha, in order to explain 心，意，神. I think need the ancient Chinese wisdom to explain it...

I tried to explain it from what I know, here you can reference it

心：无形无相 = heart/core：(shapeless, formless)

意：眼耳鼻舌身意的六根之一

神：let break this word and see, it's the combination of 示 and 申

示 means show

申 come from the basic word of 田(means farm or field)

When 田 become 申 it's show it connected or pass through to sky and ground or top or bottom, so this word 神 have the meaning of god.

When you are using 留神 this word it's have some meaning like stay focus.

Comment: I think the meaning of 神 in 留神 means *spirit*, not "god"

Comment: I never say that meaning of 神 in 留神 is god

Comment: I was explaining the single word bro